# 'Unable to locate an element with the xpath' error in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

So I am trying to login into my instagram account using phantomJS. 
However I get a an error on the fourth line ("dom...")

warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
Traceback (most recent call last):

and the traceback call concludes with selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message:
errorMessage":"Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression

What is the cause of this error?

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
dom = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//')
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
username = dom.find_element_by_name('username')
password = dom.find_element_by_name('password')
login_button = dom.find_element_by_xpath('//[@class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0"]')
username.clear()
password.clear()
username.send_keys('your username')
password.send_keys('your password')
login_button.click()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')
if 'logged-in' in driver.page_source:
  print 'Logged in'
```

Comment: Which line causes the `Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression error`? Is it the variable `dom` or the variable `login_button`?

Comment: dom = driver.find_element_by_xpaht('//')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to select all of the elements in an html document via xpath is `//*` the correct, full, xpath for the login button is `//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/span[1]/button`

Comment: @TRogue1 was this helpful or did you get another error message?

Comment: It worked, thank you! had to change
login_button = dom.find_element_by_xpath('//[@class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0"]')

to login_button = dom.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0"]') as well